# NSSearchFiled resign first responder

Tags: cocoa, resignfirstresponder, nssearchfield

I have following code snippet to create NSSearchField programmatically

```
mysearchField = [ [ NSSearchField alloc ] init];

[[mysearchField cell] setPlaceholderString:@"Page Number & Press Enter"];
[myView addSubview: mysearchField ];

    [mysearchField resignFirstResponder];

[mysearchField release];

[mysearchField setDelegate:self];
```

Here I am trying to resignFirstResponder to the mysearchField,But mysearchField is still focussing on application launch.

Am I missing some thing.

Comment: Where is the code? init or viewDidLoad?

Comment: This Code present in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[myView.window makeFirstResponder:nil];` Never call resignFirstResponder directly.